# Unit test an asynchronous callback method that is used when peek is completed

Tags: c#, moq, mstest, msmq

I wish to unit test a callback method that is called when a peek to a messagequeue is completed and can't figure out how to do this.

My abstract class;

```
public abstract class QueueHandler : WindowsServiceBase
{
    private readonly IMessageQueueWrapper _listeningQueue;
    private PeekCompletedEventHandler _peekHandler;

    protected QueueHandler(IMessageQueueWrapper listeningQueue) 
        : base()
    {
        _listeningQueue = listeningQueue;
    }

    protected override void ExecuteInternal()
    {
        _listeningQueue.BeginPeek();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureInternal()
    {
        if (_peekHandler != null) return;

        _peekHandler = OnPeekCompleted;
        _listeningQueue.PeekCompleted += OnPeekCompleted;
    }

    protected void OnPeekCompleted(object sender, PeekCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var msg = _listeningQueue.EndPeek(e.AsyncResult);

            ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

My concrete class used for unittesting;

```
internal class QueueuHandlerImplementation : QueueHandler
{
    public QueueuHandlerImplementation(IMessageQueueWrapper listeningQueue)
        : base(listeningQueue)
    {
    }
}
```

My unit test;

```
public void OnPeekCompletedWhenBeginPeekShouldCallOnPeekCompleted()
{
        QueueuHandlerImplementation queueHandler = new QueueuHandlerImplementation(_listeningQueueMock.Object);

    //Arrange
    queueHandler.Configure();
    _listeningQueueMock.Setup(m => m.BeginPeek()).Raises(
                    m => m.PeekCompleted += null, new PeekCompletedEventArgs() { AsyncResult = new Mock<IAsyncResult>().Object});

    //Act
    _queueHandler.Execute();

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(true, _queueHandler.IsConfigured);
}
```

This is not possible since `PeekCompletedEventArgs` does not have a default constructor.

```
public void OnPeekCompletedWhenBeginPeekShouldCallOnPeekCompleted()
{
        QueueuHandlerImplementation queueHandler = new QueueuHandlerImplementation(_listeningQueueMock.Object);

    //Arrange
    queueHandler.Configure();
    _listeningQueueMock.Setup(m => m.BeginPeek()).Raises(
                m => m.PeekCompleted += null, PeekCompletedEventArgs.Empty);

    //Act
    _queueHandler.Execute();

    //Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(true, _queueHandler.IsConfigured);
}
```

This looks nice but when calling execute i get an error saying Object of type "'System.EventArgs' cannot be converted to type 'System.Messaging.PeekCompletedEventArgs'."... and I don't have any AsyncResult to take care of if I would get that far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an instance using the internal constructor:

```
MessageQueue sender = null;
IAsyncResult result = null;
var e = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(System.Messaging.PeekCompletedEventArgs),
                                 BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                 null, new object[]{sender, result}, null);
```

Note: The fact that `sender` is `null` will lead to a NullReferenceException when you access the `Message` property.